What is exactly Randstorm vulnerability?
I've read the article from Unciphered about it, multiple times, and still fail to understand it
It basically says that wallets generated by BitcoinJs front end library from 2011 to 2015 are vulnerable because of the poor randomness generation. Especially those generated between May 4, 2011 to March 2012
But it's really vague on explaining what the actual exploit is. It could be just summarized as: it used Math.random() for randomness before March 2014, and it is a bad function
Let's look at the initial commit from March 4, 2011 : eckey.js is used for generating the private key, while rng.js and prng4.js in the jsbn folder are used for harvesting randomness.
rng.js
If rng_pool is not already initialized, it is filled with random values from Math.random()
while(rng_pptr < rng_psize) {  // extract some randomness from Math.random()
    t = Math.floor(65536 * Math.random());
    rng_pool[rng_pptr++] = t >>> 8;
    rng_pool[rng_pptr++] = t & 255;
  }

Math.random() according to the article has the cycle of 2^60 values before they repeat. The article also mentions that it fails modern benchmark tests, but I'm not sure about them
Is Math.random() the whole weakness of the story? What is the weakness actually about?
Later, the time in milliseconds is seeded to the pool
function rng_seed_time() {
  rng_seed_int(new Date().getTime());
}

And later for
SecureRandom.prototype.nextBytes = rng_get_bytes;

we initialize the state, and pass the pool as the key into the RC4 cipher
rng_state = prng_newstate();
rng_state.init(rng_pool);

from prng4.js
prng4.js
which creates a 256 value array
this.S = new Array();

and fills it with the loop
for(i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    j = (j + this.S[i] + key[i % key.length]) & 255;
    t = this.S[i];
    this.S[i] = this.S[j];
    this.S[j] = t;
  }

eckey.js
eckey.js uses SecureRandom() and creates our private key
var rng = new SecureRandom();
....
this.priv = ECDSA.getBigRandom(n);

But again, this tells us next to nothing about the actual vulnerability and what attacks might be used. Unciphered's article suggests that if we have GUID or IV (I guess that's a public key?), then we can do the work with just 2^32 to 2^64 values (2^48 most commonly)
Also, not sure about the clicks being added in the entropy pool, apart from:
<body onClick='rng_seed_time();' onKeyPress='rng_seed_time();'> comment.
In what way, other things are added into entropy pool apart from the initial timestamp seed?
Edit July 23, 2024:
Sorry, I forgot that ecdsa.js also has its own context
ecdsa.js
Basically, getBigRandom() method is realized in this file with rng = new SecureRandom();
Bitcoin.ECDSA = (function () {
var ecparams = getSECCurveByName("secp256k1");
var rng = new SecureRandom();
....
var ECDSA = {
getBigRandom: function (limit) {
return new BigInteger(limit.bitLength(), rng)
.mod(limit.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))
.add(BigInteger.ONE)
;
},

.

Summary: this code if(navigator.appName == "Netscape" && navigator.appVersion < "5" && window.crypto) tests against 5 in the wrong direction and (for additional reasons) ends up not taken, so that Math.random() and Date().getTime() end up as the only source of entropy, with the former having a small state in some browsers. When on top of that Math.random() is seeded by Date().getTime(), it's even easier to enumerate possible private keys.

@fgrieu Let me get this straight. In rng.js , rng_pool  is only seeded with Math.random() in the while(rng_pptr < rng_psize) loop and with Date().getTime() in rng_seed_time() function i.e. these are the only sources of entropy. Then we initialize the state with that pool rng_state.init(rng_pool); and all of this in order to create SecureRandom() {} class which will eventually be used to generate the private key like this.priv = ECDSA.getBigRandom(n) in eckey.js. What's the difference between the pool and the state (rng_pool  and rng_state)?

My reading is that rng_pool is where bytes generated by Math.random() or directly from Date().getTime() accumulate. The transformation from the horodate in second since 1970 and the content of rng_pool is almost deterministic and essentially public (with pesky exceptions like earlier uses of Math.random() or time elapsed, and exactly what browser is used). And then all the rest from that to the ECDSA private key is deterministic and public (though it takes some off-topic programming effort to exactly reproduce).

@fgrieu You're saying that rng_pool is almost deterministic and almost public, but then if we initialize our rng_state.init(rng_pool); in the line 52 of rng.js, we basically input our rng_pool into Arcfour() in prng4.js to get  rng_state and it is solidly deterministic and public?

Yes as far as I understand everything from rng_pool to the private key is deterministic and public. When Math.random() is seeded by the time in some poorly designed browser's Javascript engine the only unknowns are when that's done, how many times Math.random() is then called before generating the key, then the (possibly even so slightly higher) Date().getTime() also used as seed. The private key follows from that. And a guess is testable from the public key or from it's hash aka address.

@fgrieu Ok, thank you!
